# SSRS: How to modify text contents programmatically?

Tags: .net, reporting-services

I have a Windows Forms application, using a Report Viewer. I have a text label that I'd like to change based on the data. Is there a way to do this?

EDIT: To clarify - the text string is not directly from the database but is based on a flag in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with a formula in the text box. Depending on what you need that could be a simple IIF or a select case statement. To put a formula into a text box just right click on the box and select properties, under the general tab there is a field that says value with a “FX” symbol next to it. If you click on that it will show you the formula editor

(Before anyone says I know its not really FX but I cant be bothered to find the font/code to get the formula symbol!)

Comment: That's the one. they certainly hide those, don't they? Wouldn't a better solution be to allow the developer to modify stuff from outside of the form? I wonder if that's in the works. It feels so archaic this way.